# Bluetooth program for android1.6

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to make a Bluetooth program work for android version 1.6. I have it working for Android version2.1. when i change the project properties and set the build target to android 1.6 ,

I get error on the following statements  as there is no support for bluetooth

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
```

Any ideas on how to make it work for android version 1.6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Bluetooth API is only [available from Android 2.0 (API level 5)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.html#api-changes) on; that's [97.5%](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) of Android users.

If you really need to run on 1.6 (API level 4), you might be able to work with the [Experimental unofficial Bluetooth API for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/). The author of that project hints at [how to make it work for both 1.x and 2.x](http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/issues/detail?id=25#c5).